# how can my call the action in my component using typescript with react redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

it shows me error every time whenever i call my action from my component. I'm using typescript with react redux.

**Error : Property 'getItem' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.**

`MY Action`

```
import * as actionTypes from "../types";
import { getItems } from "../api/allApi";

export const getItem = () => {
  const payload = getItems();

  return {
    type: actionTypes.GET_ITEM,
    payload
  };
};
```

`My Component`

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/settings.scss";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { getItem } from "../Actions/action";

class Settings extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItem(); // error here: Property 'getItem' does not exist on //type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

              {console.log(this.props.items)} // Error here: Property 'items' //does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'
              {/* {console.log("asda", this.props.items)} */}
       </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  return {
    items: state.getItemsReducer
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return bindActionCreators({ getItem }, dispatch);
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Settings);
```

Comment: Also, it would be good to not leave a lot of `any's`. For example the return type of `mapStateToProps` is `IProps` or `Partial<IProps>`, if you decide to populate with more props. Also, it's state should be `state:{ getItemsReducer: soneType[]}`. Not sure about the actual output but you can figure it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create Props and pass them to your component. This props should include `getItms: Function`. You are telling the component to render s children collection he doesn't know exist.

You can do it like so:

```
export interface IProps {getItems: Function, Items:any[]} //See if you can figure out the type here

export class ComponentName extends Component<IProps, {}> {
 ...rest of the code here
}
```

Comment: THANKS @Dimitris now i can call my action any also im getting the data from api in my console as well but now i'm not getting the data to render in the screen. how can i get access the data from the api for expample a Object and want to access its child array of Object.

Comment: If `this.props.items`, is printed in the console, you should be able to use it in your render method the same way. Now, depending what the items is (Object or Array of Objects), you can just map through them. For example: `this.props.items.map(item => do something here)`. You should be able to print it in the screen.

Just make sure, that you pass a key as well. Possible the index of the items, or something else unique..

Answer (score 0):

You should create the interfaces for props (and state) for the component `Settings`.

```
interface ISettingsProps { 
  items: [] | {} //whatever may be the datatype.
  getItem(): void
}
```

And pass it to the class like this

`class Settings extends React.Component<ISettingsProps> {...}`